# Disable click event on text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery, when a user clicks on a td, it reads the text of the td and then does a redirect. How can I disable the click event if the user is selecting the text instead clicking on the td?

```
$("td").click(function() {
    var brand = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-brand");
    var url = window.btoa(window.location.toString());
    window.location = "?page=sku&action=brand&brand=" + brand + "&b=" + url;
});
```

Comment: you could use http://api.jquery.com/select/ but it works only for form elements

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here we go, I was able to figure it out using a function found [here](http://motyar.blogspot.no/2010/02/get-user-selected-text-with-jquery-and.html) to get the page's selected text, if no selection was found follow link otherwise do nothing.

```
$("td").click(function() {
    var sel = getSelected();
    if (sel === "") {
        var brand = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-brand");
        var url = window.btoa(window.location.toString());
        window.location = "?page=sku&action=brand&brand=" + brand + "&b=" + url;
    }
});

function getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        return document.getSelection().toString();
    } else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
        if (selection.text) {
            return selection.text.toString();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: A few years later and this answer is still useful. I do have a question though: is the additional complexity in the getSelected function to cover older browsers? If not, why did you need that?

Comment: I think this function can be cleaner: last return not needed, 'else' block not needed too just write code inside in outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this

```
function getSelected() {
   return (window.getSelection) ? window.getSelection().toString() : document.getSelection().toString();
}
```